# Wanting to allocate more space from a Windows partition to Ubuntu (budgie) but my boot partition is in the way

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I've been dual booting both Windows 10 and Ubuntu (the Budgie flavour) for a while now, and as I like Ubuntu I'm considering allocating more space on my hard drive for it, shrinking the Windows partition in the process. However, my current partition table, according to [gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG9ia.png) and parted, looks like this:

```
Model: SK hynix BC501 HFM256GDJTNG-8310A (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  379MB  377MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      379MB   513MB  134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      513MB   192GB  192GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      192GB   193GB  512MB   fat32                                      boot, esp
 6      193GB   255GB  62.4GB  ext4
 4      255GB   256GB  923MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

The Windows partition is the largest, currently taking up about 178.5GB. Right next to it is what I believe is the boot partition I created when setting up the dual boot (housing GRUB) using up around 500MB space, then my 60GB Ubuntu partition.

If I wanted to shrink my Windows partition and allocate the space to Ubuntu, I understand this would require moving both the boot partition and the main Ubuntu partition and I also understand that this could potentially break my bootloader. What am I supposed to do here? Is there a set of steps where I need to reinstall GRUB after resizing/moving the partitions?

Comment: Probably the safest way would be to back up your important data, shrink windows and remake Ubuntu partitions and re install.

Comment: Use Windows Disk Manager. It will tell you minimum Windows size and shrink Windows for you. It may not shrink Windows as much as you like due to fragmentation of NTFS, I would not use GParted to shrink your Windows partition without study, There are better de-frag tools around than MS makes. Good luck

Comment: @wopnoenoe 1) Don't defragment your drive; NVMe drives are solid state and defragmentation of solid state drives is not useful and not good. 2) `sudo parted -l` gives you a text version of gparted which is easier to paste into questions here. 3) Partitions /dev/nvme0n1p2, /dev/nvme0n1p3, and /dev/nvme0n1p4 all belong to Windows; /dev/nvme0n1p1 belongs to GPT disk partitioning.  /dev/nvme0n1p3 is the Windows Data and Programs partition to resize with Windows Disk Manager.

Comment: @K7AAY I added the output of sudo parted -l to the post. My main issue here is the 512MB partition #5. If I were to reduce the size of the Windows (in Windows Disk Manager), would I then need to move both partitions 5 and 6 before resizing partition 6? And would I then need to do some extra things to make my pc even able to boot into Ubuntu?